# Where does Google search get its ICC cricket world cup live commentary from?

Tags: google-search

In the recently being held ICC cricket world cup 2023, the Google search also has the option to display live cricket world cup commentary as shown below ([source](https://www.google.com/search?q=icc%20wc&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN1014IN1014&oq=icc%20wc&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRiPAjIHCAIQIRiPAtIBCDI1MjBqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=m;/g/11v13dkc5_;5;/m/021vk;cm;fp;1;;;)):

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I tried to search many different websites to search for the source of this commentary but I could not find one. Is it a Google original content?

1. Live commentary at [ICC official website](https://www.cricketworldcup.com/match/102748):
   [image: Image 3]
2. Live commentary at [Cricbuzz](https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/75420/pak-vs-ned-2nd-match-icc-cricket-world-cup-2023):
   [image: Image 4]
3. Live commentary at [espncricinfo](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/icc-cricket-world-cup-2023-24-1367856/netherlands-vs-pakistan-2nd-match-1384393/ball-by-ball-commentary):
   [image: Image 5]
4. Live commentary at [cricket world](https://www.cricketworld.com/cricket/pakistan-vs-netherlands/match/commentary/64457):
   [image: Image 6]
5. Live commentary at [The Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/icc-world-cup/pakistan-vs-netherlands-icc-odi-world-cup-2023-live-cricket-score-updates-from-hyderabad/liveblog/104206430.cms):
   [image: Image 7]
6. Live commentary at [ABP News](https://news.abplive.com/sports/cricket/pak-vs-ned-score-live-updates-icc-world-cup-match-pakistan-vs-netherlands-live-commentary-full-scorecard-1634149):
   [image: Image 8]
7. Live commentary at [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/sport/live/cricket/66854208/page/6):
   [image: Image 9]
8. Live commentary at [The Hindu](https://sportstar.thehindu.com/cricket/icc-cricket-world-cup/pak-vs-ned-live-score-odi-world-cup-2023-pakistan-netherlands-scorecard-highlights-hyderabad-streaming-updates/article67387719.ece):
   [image: Image 10]
9. Live commentary at [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/live/2023/oct/05/england-v-new-zealand-cricket-world-cup-2023-opener-live-updates)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about using a web app. Take the [Tour] & review [ask]. Depending on the underlying problem (eg. developing a web app to access a feed; questioning the legality of repurposing content; etc.) it may be a fit on another site. [Complete List of Stack Exchange sites w/ descriptions](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the blocks shown in Google search results or linked from them include links with the details you are looking for.

Professional event organizers sell broadcasting rights. Google should be granted access to official broadcastings for professional event information. So, to get the details, like who is the author of each comment, you might have to ask the league and, more specifically, the responsible for each match broadcasting.

For the details, look at https://supporg.google.com/websearch and https://blog.google/. The first is the help center of Google (the search engine product). The second is the Google corporate blog addressed to a broad audience. On it, they post about the company goals, strategies, products, technologies, relations with consumers and all kinds of entities. They have likely posted something about the relationships with professional sports leagues, sports scoreboards, and related data.

It might also be possible that someone takes all the hassle to collect this data to use it, i.e., for copyright compliance, market analysis and academic research, among other purposes.